# Getting a three.js demo to work on codesandbox?

Tags: three.js, codesandbox

I'm trying to get a 3js demo to work on codesandbox, or codepen or jsfiddle (any is fine). I think the issue is perhaps that the script is module based, but I'm not sure what to google.

This is the demo I want to copy onto one of these platforms
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instan#webgl_instancing_performance

My attempt (replaced relative path modules with CDNs)
https://codesandbox.io/s/gltf-instances-yly6m?file=/src/index.js

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript modules requires the script to have `type="module"`

```
<script src="src/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

More information here under "Applying the module to your HTML" section:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html

Codesandbox lets you add npm dependencies on the left under "Dependencies" and use them in the javascript file.
Attached a screenshot:
[image: Codesandbox npm package import]

Codepen also lets you add npm packages in the "Pen settings" section:
[image: Codepen npm package import]